# Error on zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper, kaa

I installed zookeeper on Ubuntu 14 but when run the command it fails. the command is:
cat /var/log/kaa/* | grep ERROR

it shows:
2017-04-19 00:20:04,197 [main] ERROR o.k.k.s.n.s.i.KaNodeInitializationService - Failed to connect to Zookeeper within 5 minutes. Kaa Node Server will be stopped. 
2017-04-19 00:45:39,668 [Kaa Node Server Shutdown Thread] ERROR o.k.k.s.c.s.a.AdminInitializationService - Error stopping Kaa Admin web server!
2017-04-19 00:45:39,668 [Kaa Node Server Shutdown Thread] ERROR o.k.k.s.c.u.KaaUncaughtExceptionHandler - Thread [Name: Kaa Node Server Shutdown Thread, id:67] uncaught exception:
2017-04-19 17:48:15,442 [main] ERROR o.k.k.s.n.s.i.KaaNodeInitializationService - Failed to connect to Zookeeper within 5 minutes. Kaa Node Server will be stopped.

But when i run this command it is ok:
sudo /usr/share/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh start

What should i do? This is the project to deploy Kaa cluster

Comment: What's the status of zookeeper(leader/follower) in other Kaa nodes?

Answer (score 0):

check the zookeeper is running or not if not run it as a service and port should open to connect zk.

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#quickstart

```
> bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server-1.properties &

> bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server-2.properties &
```