# ERROR o.k.k.s.n.s.i.KaaNodeInitializationService - Failed to connect to Zookeeper within 5 minutes. Kaa Node Server will be stopped

Tags: kaa

I have the same error as this topic here: [Error on zookeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43496630/error-on-zookeeper) but Zookeeper is running. Am I missing an entry in Kaa or a setting somewhere not mentioned in the Kaa install.

Thanks

Comment: Are you in a single node setup? Which is the version of the kaa server you are using? what is the result of `sudo /usr/share/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh status` and `sudo service zookeperd status`?

Comment: V10 of kaa

root@KAA:/home/ted# /usr/share/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh status
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /etc/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
Mode: standalone

root@KAA:/home/shane# service zookeperd status
● zookeperd.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)

root@KAA:/home/ted# systemctl status zookeeper
● zookeeper.service - LSB: centralized coordination service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/zookeeper; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-06-23 20:59:08 NZST; 5 days ago

Comment: Can you install zookeperd `sudo apt-get install zookeeperd`, start zookeperd (if not started by default) and restart the kaa-node service?

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion but that is one of the things I did install in order to get zookeeper to run on startup. I have version 3.4.8-1 of Zookeeperd

Comment: Did you try checking the zookeeper port availability? What is shown with command 'netstat -ntlp | grep 2181' ?

Comment: i get: tcp6       0      0 :::2181                 :::*                    LISTEN      1143/java

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

1. sudo /usr/share/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh restart
2. sudo service kaa-node restart 
   wait a minutes => Done!